# функция iconv

Tags: php, javascript

Если у меня

```
 function load() {
  document.getElementById('button_my').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('my').innerHTML = '' + '';
  document.getElementById('choise_area').setAttribute("class", "choise_area1");
  return false;
  }
```

и в ковычках много текста, то как мне испльзовать функцию iconv

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы строите JavaScript с помощю PHP, тупо:

```
document.getElementById('my').innerHTML = '' <?=iconv(...) ?> '';
```